# Error from nsis： nsis output setup.exe cannnot be overwrited

Tags: nsis

I am getting this error： `nsis output setup.exe cannnot be overwrited`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There will be one of two issues here:

1. There is a handle open on it. Most probable cause for this is that it's running.
2. You don't have permissions to write to it.